# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable in python cdsapi

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve data with the help of cdsapi module of python. but is is giving following error

```
    2020-10-19 12:55:52,780 INFO Sending request to https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api/v2/resources/reanalysis-era5-press
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cds.py", line 10, in <module>
    }, 'download.grib')
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cdsapi/api.py", line 229, in retrieve
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cdsapi/api.py", line 241, in _api
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cdsapi/api.py", line 358, in wrapped
  File "/home/apps/SiteSoftwares/gnu/PYTHONPACKAGES/2.7.9/ucs4/gnu/4.8.5/REQUESTS/2.18.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/req.4-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/apps/SiteSoftwares/gnu/PYTHONPACKAGES/2.7.9/ucs4/gnu/4.8.5/REQUESTS/2.18.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/req.4-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/apps/SiteSoftwares/gnu/PYTHONPACKAGES/2.7.9/ucs4/gnu/4.8.5/REQUESTS/2.18.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/req.4-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/home/apps/SiteSoftwares/gnu/PYTHONPACKAGES/2.7.9/ucs4/gnu/4.8.5/REQUESTS/2.18.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/req.4-py2.7.egg/requests/models.py", line 309, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "/home/apps/SiteSoftwares/gnu/PYTHONPACKAGES/2.7.9/ucs4/gnu/4.8.5/REQUESTS/2.18.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/req.4-py2.7.egg/requests/models.py", line 540, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I have registered and install cdsapi client key as suggested in the following link

https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api-how-to

My simple code snipet is shown below

```
import cdsapi
cds = cdsapi.Client()
cds.retrieve('reanalysis-era5-pressure-levels', {
"variable": "temperature",
"pressure_level": "1000",
"product_type": "reanalysis",
"date": "2017-12-01/2017-12-31",
"time": "12:00",
"format": "grib"
}, 'download.grib')
```

what is wrong in this ??

Comment: Please post the complete error message including backtrace.

Comment: posted a detailed error. Please look into this

Comment: try changing python version. for me 3.6 couldn't import the package and 3.7 run the code without problems

Comment: same error with python 3.7

Answer (score 6):

It's not very obvious from the [instructions](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api-how-to#install-the-cds-api-key) if you are logged in, but under the `key` field of your `.cdsapirc` file, you need **both** the user ID and api key as:

```
key: $user_id:$api_key
```

I had this problem as well and solved it by including my user ID.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. After login to Copernicus website and accept the license terms in following URL, my problem is solved:

https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp/#!/terms/licence-to-use-copernicus-products

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved.
There is problem in ~/.cdsapirc file which needs to be configured properly.
After configuring, program is running well.

Comment: would be good if you went into detail, having the same error

Comment: @Rafael perhaps you are missing your user ID in the `key` field?